# find posts with exactly 3/4 categories

Tags: posts, categories

I see wordpress gives you opportunity for searching posts with exactly N categories...so i tried by myself and produced this code...

```
$catIDs = get_cat_ID( $cat_name='CategoryName1' );
$catIDs .= ',' . get_cat_ID( $cat_name='CategoryName2');
$catIDs .= ',' . get_cat_ID( $cat_name='CategoryName3');
echo "$catIDs </br>";

$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array($catIDs) ) );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_ID(); ?> </a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

if i replace the array($catIDs) with 1,2,3 (the ID of the category) this solution works....why with the variable $catIDs it doesn't? and how can i make this solution dynamic (i have a form and i would pass the data in this form -category name/ID in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure you are providing correct category names into the function get_cat_ID().**

```
<?php 
$catIDs = array();
$catIDs[] = get_cat_ID( 'CategoryName1' );
$catIDs[] = get_cat_ID( 'CategoryName2' );
$catIDs[] = get_cat_ID( 'CategoryName3' );

$my_query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'category__and' => $catIDs 
    ) 
);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_ID(); ?> </a>
        </li> <?php 
    endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

Comment: Missed the part 'making this dynamic': You need to create a array out of form submitted category ids/ category names and do the same as above.